# How to use Multiple buttons with different controller in angularjs for redirecting

Tags: javascript, angularjs

I wrote the program that is having 3 buttons and if i click on the particular button it should redirect to corresponding page mentioned in app.js

> my requirement is each button should have a controller and it should redirect properly and it should show a console message that which button is clicked
>   i'm sharing my code but it is not working

## index.html

```
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html>

<head>
  <meta charset="utf-8" />
  <title>Test</title>

  <link data-require="bootstrap-css" data-semver="3.1.1" rel="stylesheet" href="//netdna.bootstrapcdn.com/bootstrap/3.1.1/css/bootstrap.min.css" />

  <!-- Le javascript
    ================================================== -->
  <script data-require="jquery" data-semver="2.0.3" src="http://code.jquery.com/jquery-2.0.3.min.js"></script>
  <script data-require="bootstrap" data-semver="3.1.1" src="//netdna.bootstrapcdn.com/bootstrap/3.1.1/js/bootstrap.min.js"></script>
   <script type="text/javascript" src="http://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/angularjs/1.2.9/angular.min.js"></script>
  <script type="text/javascript" src="http://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/angularjs/1.2.9/angular-route.min.js"></script>


  <script>var myItemsApp = angular.module('myItemsApp', ['ngRoute']);</script>

</head>

<body ng-app="myItemsApp">
  <div>
    <h3>Test</h3>
    <div class="row">
      <div class="col-md-4">

            <button href="/test1" ng-click="submit1()">Button1</button>
            <button href="/test2" ng-click="submit2()">Button2</button>
            <button href="/test3" ng-click="submit3()">Button3</button>


        </div>
      </div>
    </div>
  </div>
    <script src="app.js"></script>
</body>

  <script src="testcntrl.js"></script>

</html>
```

#app.js

```
  myItemsApp.config(['$routeProvider',function($routeProvider) {

      $routeProvider

      .when('/test1', {
        templateUrl : 'test.html',
        controller  : 'button1Controller'
      })

       .when('/test2', {
        templateUrl : 'test1.html',
        controller  : 'button2Controller'
      })

        .when('/test3', {
        templateUrl : 'test2.html',
        controller  : 'button3Controller'
      })

       .otherwise({
           redirectTo: '/'

      });


}]);
```

## testcntrl.js

```
myItemsApp.controller('button1Controller', ['$scope','$location', function($scope,location){


    $scope.submit1 = function() {

    console.log("I clicked on submit button1Controller");

    location.path('/test1');
    }

}]); 

myItemsApp.controller('button2Controller', ['$scope','$location', function($scope,location){


    $scope.submit2 = function() {

        console.log("I clicked on submit button2Controller ");

    location.path('/test2');
    }

}]); 


myItemsApp.controller('button3Controller', ['$scope','$location', function($scope,location){


    $scope.submit3 = function() {

        console.log("I clicked on submit button3Controller");

    location.path('/test3');
    }

}]);
```

## test1.html

```
<h1>hello</h1>
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Your idea is ok, it should work but:

- No need href in button.
- Instead of button you can simply use anchor with #/test1 #/test2
- If you still want this way you need another controller "main controller"

This can work:

```
// Code goes here
var myItemsApp = angular.module('myItemsApp', ['ngRoute']);
myItemsApp.config(['$routeProvider', function($routeProvider) {

  $routeProvider

    .when('/test1', {
    templateUrl: 'test1.html',
    controller: 'button1Controller'
  })

  .when('/test2', {
    templateUrl: 'test2.html',
    controller: 'button2Controller'
  })

  .when('/test3', {
    templateUrl: 'test3.html',
    controller: 'button3Controller'
  })

  .otherwise({
    redirectTo: '/'

  });


}]);



myItemsApp.controller('initialController', ['$scope', '$location', function($scope, location) {


  $scope.submit1 = function() {
    console.log("I clicked on submit button1Controller");
    location.path('/test1');
  }

  $scope.submit2 = function() {
    console.log("I clicked on submit button2Controller ");
    location.path('/test2');
  }

  $scope.submit3 = function() {
    console.log("I clicked on submit button3Controller");
    location.path('/test3');
  }
}]);

myItemsApp.controller('button1Controller', ['$scope', '$location', function($scope, location) {

}]);

myItemsApp.controller('button2Controller', ['$scope', '$location', function($scope, location) {

}]);


myItemsApp.controller('button3Controller', ['$scope', '$location', function($scope, location) {

}]);
```

[Plunker demo](http://plnkr.co/edit/cg2ZiibjPtsOlJguGNJP?p=preview)

Comment: :- it works but the page is not redirecting anywhere just the url only changing..

Comment: I added  a ng-view in index.html it works now (Y)  <div ng-view></div>

Answer (score 3):

You should add `ng-view` to render template. and add `#` to `url` in the `href`.

also you don't need `ng-click` when time using `<a>` tag.and you injected service into controller incorrectly. you should inject `$location` instead of `location`

if you want to remove `#` from url so enable html mode.

```
 <div class="col-md-4">

        <a href="#/test1" >Button1</a>
        <a href="#/test2" >Button2</a>
        <a href="#/test3" >Button3</a>


    </div>
    <div ng-view=""></div>
  </div>
```

[Demo](http://plnkr.co/edit/mwj3I9fenqiooX6P4MI6?p=preview)

Comment: Yes it can work but I think he wants to use the ngroute.